# How to set the default product image for Magento multisite?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have a script that loads a directory and add every directory's image to my products.

Until yesterday I had just one website and this script was setting the first image of every product as the "default" image for the product.

Today I've added a new website with two store views and the script keeps adding every image to the products, but doesn't sets anymore the first image for every product as the "default" image anymore.

I believe that the problem is some kind related to the 2 stores. But after googling all day I can't figure how can I fix this.

This is my code:

```
while (every file in dir) {
   // code to get sku from image filename

   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
   if ($posicion == 0) {
      $tipoImages = array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image');
   } else {
      $tipoImages = NULL;
   }
   $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
   $mediaGalleryAttribute = $attributes['media_gallery'];
   $file = $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->addImage($product, $dir . "/" . $f, $tipoImages, false, false);
   $data = array(
                    'label' => '',
                    'position' => $posicion,
                    'disabled' => false,
                    'exclude' => false
                );
   $product->save();
   $posicion++;
}
```

What do I need to change or add to set the first image of every product as the default image?